# Can't run 2 consecutive tests (Wanted but not invoked Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock)

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, viewmodel

There's actually a couple of similar questions here, but I've tried all the suggestions, and still facing this problem.

```
Wanted but not invoked:
observer.onChanged(<Repo matcher>);
-> at xxx.RepoViewModelTest.testRepoList(RepoViewModelTest.kt:51)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

class RepoViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    @Mock private lateinit var observer: Observer<DataWrapper<List<Repo>>>
    @Mock private lateinit var repoRepository: RepoRepository
    private lateinit var repoViewModel: RepoViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        repoViewModel = RepoViewModel(RepoUseCase(repoRepository))
    }

    @Test
    fun testError() {
        `when`(repoRepository.getRepos("mine"))
            .thenReturn(Observable.error(Exception("No internet")))
        repoViewModel.observeRepos().observeForever(observer)
        repoViewModel.getRepos("mine")    
        verify(observer).onChanged(
            argThat(RepoMatcher(DataWrapper(Exception("No internet")))))
    }

    @Test
    fun testRepoList() {
        val listIn = listOf(Repo("Repo1"), Repo("Repo2"))
        `when`(repoRepository.getRepos("mine"))
            .thenReturn(Observable.just(listIn))
        repoViewModel.observeRepos().observeForever(observer)
        repoViewModel.getRepos("mine")
        val listOut = listOf(Repo("Repo1"), Repo("Repo2"))
        verify(observer)
            .onChanged(argThat(RepoMatcher(DataWrapper(listOut))))
    }
}
```

I can run each test individually just fine, but not the whole suite.
I've tried to reset the mocks after each test, create one observer per test, or instantiate each mock object inside each test, no dice.

Running tests in Android Studio 3.2.1, under app/xxx/test

mockito 2.8.47

java 1.8.0_191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need something like this

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler(__ -> Schedulers.trampoline());
}
```